# iTunes Connect Subscription Status URL never called

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit

We need our server to receive notifications about changes in subscription statuses.
To achieve this we followed the instructions from https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev0067a330b.

Our server supports App Transport Security (ATS) protocol. It was tested with this service https://apptransport.info/. So all requirements seem to be fulfilled.

We entered the target URL into the “Subscription Status URL” field. But we haven’t received a request (GET, POST, PUT) to the specified address after starting and expiring subscriptions in our sandbox.

Is there any way to troubleshoot this kind of problem?

Comment: You are definitely not the only one. This feature appears to be broken for a lot of us. I have been in contact with with Apple via bugreport.apple.com for several months now and they don't seem to be aware of what is going on.

Comment: In our case bugreport.apple.com solved the problem. The reason was really simple. Our endpoint required authorisation Apple server was unable to provide.

Comment: Was it not https? More specifics as to what kind of authorisarion?

Comment: Our server answered with 403 status because of REST API misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple support helped us to find out the reason of our problem.

> We are receiving a 403 response for server notifications that are
>   being sent by the App Store.

So we should try it with *curl* before asking this question. Now we receive updates correctly.

Comment: What did you tried with `curl`? What kind of call ?

Comment: @KevinMachado the solution in our cases was to check our url is working before submitting it to Appstore. 

You can test it with any debugging HTTP client. wget, curl for command line or if you like GUI tools I'd recommend to test it with Postman or Paw. 

For example:

curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"test": "test"}' https://your.server.com/api/v1/apple/update_status/

Take a look at the link suggested by Kelly. This method wouldn't help if you have problems with certificates. Try tool suggested in the article.

Answer (score 2):

Just finished resolving a similar issue after submitting a bug report. A different underlying problem, we were missing the intermediate CA on our SSL certificate. curl on macOS didn't alert us to the error, but curl on linux did. I wrote up a summary of the issue and how to test it here: 
https://deciphertools.com/blog/subscription-status-url-not-working/